# How can I make an Android app catch a redirect by javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, charts

this is my first time asking a question here since I can't find a solution anywhere. I am currently working on the backend of an Android application. The server uses Google Charts to generate some graphics info we need. I used this tutorial http://www.battlehorse.net/page/topics/charts/save_google_charts_as_image.html
to convert the charts into images. However this method only works when you click on buttons. I actually need to send the images to the Android app, so I introduced this to the html code

```
saveAsImg(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

after drawing the chart with the Google Chart tool. And I changed the saveAsImg function on my script to this

```
function saveAsImg(chartContainer) {
    var imgData = getImgData(chartContainer);
    window.location.href= imgData;
  }
```

Now on the side of my Android app, I make the requests to the server using httpUrlConnection. The problem is that it gets the http code but it won't catch the redirection, so it doesn't show the graphs that I need. Also I don't want to use a webView, I want to send the url with the png in code64 like I currently do so the app can just get the image.

Please let me know if there is more information I can give you. Thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to run in a WebView and then use the Webview's Javascript interface to connect back into your Android app?

Comment: Yeah that is kinda what I am doing right now. The thing is that if it is opened from an Android version lower than 3.0 it won't work since that version does not support SVG. Also I can't change the size of the img, so if I want to use the web service from a phone with a small screen I will have to scroll.